# I can't get site.tags[some_tag].size in Jekyll

Tags: tags, size, jekyll, liquid

I've tried to show tag cloud in my jekyll blog like below

https://superdevresources.com/tag-cloud-jekyll/

but, I cannot access tag.tags.size

this is code of `sidebar.html`

```
{% assign tags = site.tags | sort %}
{% for tag in tags %}
  <span>
    <a href="/tags/{{ tag.slug }}" class="tag-reverse">
      <span>{{ tag.name }}</span>
      <span>({{ tag.tags.size }})</span>
                    ^ This is always null
    </a>{% unless forloop.last %}{% endunless %}
  </span>
{% endfor %}
```

I think that `size` of `tag.tags` is represent the number of posts in the specific tag. but null has always come, even though there are posts in the tag

FYI, This is some of `_config.xml`

```
# Tags
collections:
  tags:
    output: true
    permalink: /tags/:path/

defaults:
  - scope:
      path: ''
      type: tags
    values:
      layout: tag
```

you can reach my blog repo at https://github.com/closer27/closer27.github.io

Thank you for helping me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ideally `site.tags` would be populated by the tags you've used. But in your case, its overridden by your `_tags` collection.

Doesn't matter, **since you have just one other collection (`_posts`), you can generate the tag-size as follows:**

```
{% for tag in site.tags %}
  <span>
    <a href="/tags/{{ tag.slug }}" class="tag-reverse">
      <span>{{ tag.name }}</span>
      <span>
        ({{ site.posts | where_exp: 'post', 'post.tags contains tag.name' | size }})
      </span>
    </a>
  </span>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know about template for jekyll. But when I put your code my source, I can just get '31' every loop, not each size of the tag. I think this is the count of all posts, I am looking for a correct expression

Comment: oh, I've got it. `where_exp` is available on v3.2.0. so I updated jekyll and it's done.